# Range Error - Loop to increase row index vba

Tags: vba, loops, range, runtime-error

This is a portion of my code. In the end, I want to loop through cells, find the text in between two phrases, concatenate that, and paste it into determined columns. Once the code finds "ID", it will add a row to the paste range, and start over. (this is near the bottom).

What I can't do, is get the range in each section to cooperate.  When I use 'wksSource.Range(Cells(R, 2)).Value = stringValues' it throws the error: 1004, Method range of object worksheet failed. But if I use 'wksSource.Range("B15").Value = stringValues' it is completely fine. The problem is, that isn't dynamic. I need 'R' to increase everytime the phrase "ID" is found. The columns will be constant for each section. (R,2) (R,3) etc.

I've done so much googling and I understand why that error is thrown; I just can't figure out why it's happening in this instance. Worksheet is defined... and it works with "B15", so I'm thinking the error is in the "R", but I am stuck.

Please help! (I realize this could probably be a loop all the way, and I'd love to hear advice on that if you want, but for now, I am trying to learn and it seems the best way for me to do that is one piece at a time. Increase rows with a small loop today, tackle big loops tomorrow. :))

```
Dim rng As Range, AllPos As Range, rngEnd As Range, rngStart As Range
 Dim DeptRng As Variant, stringValues As String, cell As Range, NextRow As Variant
 Dim R As Integer, lastRowCon As Integer, wksSource As Worksheet, paste As Range

 Set AllPos = Range("A2:A53")
 R = 2
 Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set rngStart = AllPos.Find("Department Description:").Cells
    If Not rngStart Is Nothing Then
        Set rngEnd = AllPos.Find("Position Duties :").Cells
        Set DeptRng = Range(rngStart, rngEnd.Offset(1))
            For Each C In DeptRng
                stringValues = stringValues & C
            Next C
           wksSource.Range(Cells(R, 2)).Value = stringValues
         stringValues = ""
    End If
```

.....several iterations of above here.....

```
Set rngStart = AllPos.Find("ID:").Cells
    If Not rngStart Is Nothing Then
'Finds last row of content
     lastRowCon = wksSource.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'Finds first row without content
    R = lastRowCon + 1
        'select next empty row, Column B
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wksSource.Cells(R, 2).Value = stringValues
```

If it's a single cell, you don't need `Range()`.

Edit: See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff836512.aspx) for further examples. If you give the `Range` property one parameter, it has to be the name of a Range. `Cells(i,j)` returns a `Range` object and you don't need/can't use `Cells(i,j)` as a name of itself. When you use `Cells(i,j)` it's like using `ActiveSheet.Cells(i,j)`, btw.

Comment: Sorry about that! Yes, it should be accepted now. Thanks again!